# use greps invert-match globally

Tags: bash, grep

Let's simulate the output of a program by `echo -e "a\nb\nc"`.
How can I tell grep to return with 0 if the whole output does not contain a given pattern, lets say simply `b`?

I tried something like `echo -e "a\nb\nc" | grep -vq b; echo $?`

Unfortunately the logic is "return 0 if there is a single line that does not contain the pattern" not "return 0 if ALL of the lines do not contain the pattern".

Is there a flag to change that? If you suggest -L, how to use the pipe input instead of a file then?

Comment: Th  `-L` option does this; `grep -Lqx b file` but it's not standard.

Comment: @tripleee but thats only for a file, i have to pipe it - how to do that then?

Comment: maybe `grep's` not the right tool? `echo -e "a\nb\nc" | read input; [[ "$input" != "b" ]] ; echo $?` => `0`; there are probably several ways to slice-n-dice that (eg,  `echo -e "a\nb\nc" | [[ "${@}" != "b" ]] ; echo $?`) though results may differ based on the shell

Comment: `printf '%s\n' a b c | grep -FLqx b - && echo yes` does not echo `yes`. Change the `b` to `d` in the input and it does. This is on a Mac; weirdly, on Ubuntu, I get the opposite.

Comment: I like the last one! Thanks, never used the - in bash